# Matching values from 2 different excel and paste the column from excel 2 to excel 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have 2  different excel. Excel 1 is with all the company name with their branch company names and sales person names. Every sales person has different excels by their name. I have to take the sales target column from sales person excel and put it in excel 1. I made a sample excels and put the screenshot here.

[Excel 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SVZU.png)

[Sales Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL7Av.png)

I guess it's a VLOOKUP, but not sure how to do this since I have to match the company and branch name. Now how can I match the company name, parent company  and sales person, then generate the target sales column in excel 1.

Any suggestion or help appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So does each person have their own workbook file, or their own worksheet in the same file as the master "sheet1"? And do you want to put the data from *n* salesperson sheets into 1 master (combine), or distribute data from master to many? I.e. will the the formulae be in the master or in each salesperson sheet?

Comment: Fyi, the best way to do a lookup on many parameters is to add a helper column and concatenate the strings together with e.g. `=A2 & B2 & C2` to form a single unique lookup key.

Comment: I find that you said "I have 2 different excel. ", and "Every sales person has different excels by their name". Do you mean you have 2 workbooks, one includes different sheets named after the sales person names?